# How can I make mat-sidenav take up entire vertical space underneath mat-toolbar?

Tags: css, angular, angular-material, css-grid, mat-sidenav

I'm trying to get the following angular-material layout working.  I have a `mat-toolbar` at the top, and `mat-sidenav` on the bottom.  No matter what I try, I can't get the `mat-sidenav-container` to take up the whole page height.  This is my attempt using grid layout.  It looks like it should work, but it doesn't.  It seems like the `mat-sidenav` automatically shrinks to the height of element inside `mat-sidenav-content`.

[image]

Here's my html:

```html
<div class="main-div">
  <app-header class="app-header"></app-header>
  <app-sidenav class="app-sidenav"></app-sidenav>
</div>
```

Here's my css:

```css
.main-div {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: auto 1fr;
}

.app-header {
  grid-column: 1 / 2;
  grid-row: 1 / 2;
}

.app-sidenav {
  grid-column: 1 / 2;
  grid-row: 2 / 3;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this

```
.main-div {
   display: grid;
   grid-template-columns: 1fr;
   grid-template-rows: auto 1fr;
   height: 100vh;
}
.mat-sidenav-container {
   height: 100%;
}
```